# aspnet auth cookie twice in Request

Tags: asp.net, authentication, session-cookies

I'm dealing with custom authentication cookie in AspNet web app.

Using `asp:Login` component, here is how user is authenticated:

```
void L_Authenticate(object sender, AuthenticateEventArgs e)
    {
        if (L.UserName == "john" && L.Password == "cookie")
        {
            FormsAuthenticationTicket ticket = 
              new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, "john", 
                                            DateTime.Now, 
                                            DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30),
                                            false, "");

            var cookieConnexion = new HttpCookie("myCookie");
            cookieConnexion.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
            cookieConnexion.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
            this.Response.Cookies.Set(cookieConnexion);

            Z.Text = "<a href='/Prive/Home.aspx'>next</a>";
        }
    }
```

First of all, I don't set `e.Authenticated = true` or `.ASPXAUTH` cookie will be created. I don't want that. Second, I don't do `Response.Redirect`.

Now, in Global.asax, User is set in current `HttpContext`:

```
protected void Application_AuthenticateRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (Request.IsAuthenticated)
   {

   }
   else
   {
        var cookie = this.Request.Cookies["myCookie"];
        if (cookie != null)
        {
           var ticket = FormsAuthentication.Decrypt(cookie.Value);

           if (ticket != null)
           {
              HttpContext.Current.User = 
                 new ClientRolePrincipal(new GenericIdentity(ticket.Name));

              ticket = new FormsAuthenticationTicket(1, ticket.Name, 
                                 DateTime.Now, 
                                 DateTime.Now.AddSeconds(30), 
                                 false, ticket.UserData);

              cookie.Value = FormsAuthentication.Encrypt(ticket);
              cookie.Expires = ticket.Expiration;
              this.Response.Cookies.Set(cookie);
            }
         }
     }
 }
```

First request to the app (using chrome dev tools, I track down cookies in request/responses headers):

- 0 cookie in request
- 0 cookie in response: ASP.NET_SessionId

User logs in:

- 1 cookie in request: ASP.NET_SessionId
- 1 cookie in response: myCookie

User browses to Home.aspx:

- 2 cookies in request: ASP.NET_SessionId, myCookie
- 1 cookie in response: myCookie (renewed)

OK.

Now, if on `PreRender` I display elements contained in this.Request.Cookies, I see twice `myCookie`. Why?

- ASP.NET_SessionId, domain '' , path '/', value = nk1cy255quh32o45hxtg4x55
- myCookie, domain '' , path '/', value = BF6246B7E5A5100AA59A7B7237B446...
- myCookie, domain '' , path '/', value = BF6246B7E5A5100AA59A7B7237B446...

Comment: Watch your network traffic in Fiddler to see whether you've got two ASPNET session cookies being set via Set-Cookie. This often happens if you have a site on example.com that redirects to www.example.com, for instance.